# Swipe functionality disables vertical scroll - Chrome for Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, scroll, slideshow, swipe

A few points to get started;

Handset: Nexus 4 (Android 4.4.4)
Browser: Chrome 36.0 (the latest update)

I am struggling to find a single article online which relates to it! Is there anybody else experiencing the same issue?

The issue; pretty much any swipe enabled horizontal slider prevents vertical scrolling. It happens on just about every website that I have tried so far.

Take, for example, the JD Sports website;

http://m.jdsports.co.uk/products/nike-air-huarache/120445

This is one of the biggest sport retailers in the UK. When I view a product page, the swipe gallery fills my entire viewport making it very difficult to scroll down to the buy button, which is hidden below the fold.

If I take a look at my favourite slider site, I can't vertically scroll when touching over a gallery;

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Is this a bug? Or do I have something wrong with my handset/browser?

Comment: I absolutely am having the same problems, within the WebView browser inside a Cordova app.  it's really a huge UX problem for my app.  I am having the additional problem that even a micro-swipe is overriding tap-hold detection, which is a key component of my user experience.  Let me know if you find anything.  Note: I am seeing this on both the Galaxy S5 and the Nexus 5.

Comment: I haven't been back to this issue since posting, but it would appear that Chrome has since released a fix. The issues on the links that I provided are no longer present. Hope you manage to fond a fix for your problem!